# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am getting crashes of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on google developer console on some devices. It is strange for me because it does not happen on my device and some others which i have tested and i also tested my apk on different versions of API'S on emulator and crash does not happen. I am totaly blind what should i do to avoid this crash as i am unable to see it.Getting crash on `button_array[btn_ref] = new Button(mContext);` Attached below is my code for button array:

```
public static Button[] button_array = null;
int btn_ref = 0;

int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {

            if (i >= 5) {

                for (int z = i; z < words.size(); z++) {
                    bonus_words.add(words.get(z));
                }
                if (!checkResult.equals("true")) {
                    tinydb.putListString("BonusList", bonus_words);
                }
                break;
            } else {
                char[] eachLetterinArray = words.get(i).toCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < eachLetterinArray.length; j++) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(eachLetterinArray[j])) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

button_array = new Button[count];

 for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            int z = words.get(i).length();

            LinearLayout ln = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            ln.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ln.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));

            row = i;
            int row_items_count_start = 0;
            int row_items_count_end = 0;

            boolean first_time_check_row = true;

for (i = 0; i < z; i++) {

                row_items_count_end = btn_ref;
                if (first_time_check_row) {
                    row_items_count_start = btn_ref;
                    first_time_check_row = false;
                }

                button_array[btn_ref] = new Button(mContext); //**Getting crash here**

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width_height_cal, width_height_cal, 0.1f);
                p.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                button_array[btn_ref].setLayoutParams(p);
                button_array[btn_ref].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                button_array[btn_ref].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.un_filled_box2);
                ln.addView(button_array[btn_ref]);

                btn_ref++;
            }

            indexes.add("row " + row + "," + row_items_count_start + "," + row_items_count_end + "," + words.get(i));
            vert_lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            vert_lay.addView(ln);

            if (indexes.size() >= 5) {
                break;
            }
```

`btn_ref` is used to save index of a button in array and after that i am putting that button array into a layout

Comment: Are you trying to create `z` about of buttons?

Comment: I have updated my question. Actually i have an arraylist of  ```words``` and i am fetching words one by one in the top loop and z contains the length of each word one by one and after that button array is created for the words

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize an array with size

```
int max_word_size = 20; //for example
public static Button[] button_array = new Button[max_word_size ];
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Actually i am getting first 5 entries of words array and then get size of each word and increment count on each letter. button_array is having a dynamic size passed to it i.e count

Comment: array has fixed size.
For dynamic size use arraylist or use an array with max supposed size

Comment: is there any difference between using this simple array Button[] button_array = new Button[max_word_size]; and ArrayList<Button> button_array = new ArrayList<>(max_word_size); ? Arent both have fixed size which we pass from a variable?

Comment: array has a fixed size. We cant change it after create. But arraylist we can remove items, add new items, change size for new task. Arraylist is more flexible

Comment: i am not changing the size of array. i am giving it a fixed size on runtime and after that populating that array. This process leads to crashes on some devices displayed on developer console